# My FIDE Initial Rating Calculation Problem

Tags: rules, fide, rating, calculation

I’m working on path to get my initial FIDE rating. I joined 8 local FIDE rated tournaments with result as follow.

- Rating = Result

Rapid Ratings November 2022
1083  = 0

Rapid Ratings March 2023
1142 = 1,
1192 = 0

Rapid Ratings April 2023
1162 = 1

Rapid Ratings May 2023
1534 = 0

Rapid Ratings June 2023
1184 = 0,
1103 = 1

Rapid Ratings July 2023
1210 = 0,
1162 = 0

Rapid Ratings Aug 2023
1245 = 1,
1150 = 0,
1119 = 1,
1092 =0

I had played more than 5 rated games with rated opponents and scored points in those games as per FIDE initial rating handbook, but I did not yet get my rating this month.
Based on my hand calculation, from the result, I might get initial rating around 1100.
Need help from expert who know the reason why above result not fulfill initial FIDE rating requirement.

Comment: Are you comfortable sharing your fide profile

Comment: First thing. Congratulations, looks like you are doing well. Secondly I'll have a look see if I can figure it out. The ELO calculation is a little goofy though so I'll see what I can figure out. the main issue you'll find is what's called the k value. Hopefully fide provides that because it's a chore to work backwards and figure out

Comment: K is not really problematic to figure out: K = 40 for a player new to the rating list until he has completed events with at least 30 games
K = 20 as long as a player's rating remains under 2400.
K = 10 once a player's published rating has reached 2400 and remains at that level subsequently, even if the rating drops below 2400.
K = 40 for all players until their 18th birthday, as long as their rating remains under 2300.
K = 20 for RAPID and BLITZ ratings all players. (https://ratings.fide.com/calc.phtml?page=change)

Comment: Additionally K is not used at all for initial calculation if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @Dheebs thank you in advance for your willingness to help. Will looking after your finding.

Comment: @MatijaSirk Yes sir, it seems that K value not counted for initial rating.

Comment: Hi that appears correct in your instance but it appears your opponents case it is. In regards to your rating your calculations look right, FIDE often drag the chain a bit and even though the results are there the initial rating hasn't been assigned. The two aren't dependent for some silly reason. If it's more than 2 months engage them directly

Comment: @Dheebs Tq sir. I found it is really confusing. Will engage them if it is still not updated.